# How to use an alias name for Angular expression?

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 7

I have following template

```
<div>
{{myService.userInfo.firstName}} {{myService.userInfo.lastName}}
</div>
```

I want to make it short by substituting `user` instead of `myService.userInfo`

```
<div>
{{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}
</div>
```

How can I do this like ng-init in AngularJS.

Comment: Define a component or a pipe that takes myService.userInfo as input/argument.

Comment: JB Nizet adds good info here, and I can explain what he/she means. If your user presentation logic is going to become more involved, it may be worth it to abstract it into a UserComponent. Next, if retrieving the data of interest is going to be an expensive operation, it will be worth it to use a pipe. A pipe caches it's output, so Angular will not recalculate the data unless the input to the pipe changes. On the other hand, a getter is calculated every change detection cycle. For cheaper operators like grabbing this username it shouldn't matter too much.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with the help of either `NgIf` or `NgForOf`.

### Solution:

So, in your case it will be:

```
<div *ngIf="myService.userInfo as user">
  {{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}
</div>
```

---

**Angular documentation for reference:**
https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#storing-conditional-result-in-a-variable
https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables

Comment: I can't see how this relates to the code in the question. What makes you think there's a `userObservable`?

Comment: @IngoBürk It's an example from Angular documentation. To which I gave the solution which he was looking for under title `So, in your case it will be:`

Comment: Delete first snippet. The 2nd snippet may work. But it would be great if there is a direct solution to this. This is a kind of hack to fix the problem.

Comment: @HariDas I have updated my answer (Removed first snippet)

Answer (score 7):

create a getter property that will return the userinfo object

```
 get user(){
      return this.myService.userInfo;
 }
```

and use like

```
<div>
   {{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}
</div>
```

Comment: Is not there any angular kind solution ? It would be really great.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a custom pipe, you can do something like this

```
@Pipe({name: 'namePipe'})
export class NamePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, prop: string): string {
     return value.userInfo[prop];
  }
}

<div>
    {{myService | namePipe:'firstName'}} {{myService | namePipe:'lastName'}}
</div>
```

But at that point you aren't saving any space in your html. You could make two pipes, and reference them like this:

```
@Pipe({name: 'firstName'})
export class FirstNamePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any): string {
     return value.userInfo.firstName;
  }
}

@Pipe({name: 'lastName'})
...

<div>
    {{myService | firstName}} {{myService | lastName}}
</div>
```

But if this is the only place you are referencing them, then it's not really worth it. You could set a variable `let user = this.myService.userInfo` but that is ugly and you will have to manually update if there is a change. Maybe you could pass your information into a child component (ask if you want to see an example) and access the fields that way, but with how little code you provided I don't know what is best for your use case. But I don't think there is clean way to achieve what you want besides the other answers given.